# XAML/C# Hiding a TextBlock if the bound value is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my WPF application I have a listview that only appears if a bound item has an values, this works like so

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,20" BorderThickness="0"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SelectionlessListViewItemStyle}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MissingAssets}">
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
```

So this will only display the listview if MissingAssets has any values and works fine, above that I wanted a textblock as a header to just say "The following assets could not be found", and I want to hide this text of course if this listview is hidden too, I tried implementing it like this

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="The following assets could not be found">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MissingAssets}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

But for some reason it won't hide even if MissingAssets is empty, I've tried using several different things in Value=""  but nothing gets it to work. Is there a property or something I'm forgetting to set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here. The simplest should be to bind the `TextBlock.Visibility` to the `ListView.Visibilty`:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Elementname="MissingAssetsListView", Path="Visbibility" />
  <ListView x:Name="MissingAssetsListView" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, I created a new string property in my C# code that remains blank unless missing assents are found, if they are found I populate the string and bind that string to a label in my XAML, so if the string is empty then there will be no visible label on the UI